# A field in the model with not counterpart in DB throws "Invalid column name"

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to define a field that's not in my database.
Its form is like this:

```
public string Adress {get;set;}
public int? Number {get;set;}
public string Name {get{
    return (this.Adress + " " + this.Number.ToString())
} set{}}
```

...and when I run the Index (whose model is of type IEnumerable), the controller throws...

```
Invalid column name 'Name'.
```

I want to do this so I don't have to concatenate all these every time.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 and SQL Server 2008.

Is there a way to tell the model I don't have a column with that name?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're doing, what technologies you're using etc please. When do you get this error? What are you doing when it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered how to do this.

It can be managed by using the [NotMapped] property.